# How to create and write to a txt document from a batch executable

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I am making a mock operating system using .bat files and I want to be able to create and write to .txt files so I can store data, but I can't find a command that lets me do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: `echo This is the text I want to write >> test.txt`.

Comment: `>` writes to a new file, `>>` appends to a file, and creates it if it does not exist already.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to export loggs to a txt file do something like

```
echo This text must be logged > log.txt
```

if you open *log.txt* after it:

```
This text must be logged
```

if you want to write in the next line or want to use a existing file,
use this

```
echo Next Line pls >> log.txt
```

so the updated *log.text* file looks like this

```
This text must be logged
Next Line pls
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write text into the txt file with more lines than try this:

```
(
echo.This is line 1
echo.This is line 2
echo.This is line 3
echo.This is line 4
echo.
echo.^:^)
) > ".\yourfilename.txt"
```

"yourfilename.txt"

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4

:)
```